# How to increase loudness of audio from targetdataline using java sound api?

Tags: java, audio, javasound

In my project I have implemented an audio record option. For reading real-time voice I used `TargetDataLine`.I want to record audio with high volume. How can I do that?

```
        TargetDataLine line;
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
        File file = new File("RecordedVoice.raw");
        if(file.exists())
            file.delete();
        file.createNewFile();
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            System.out.println("Line not supported: " + format.toString());
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            try {
                line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                line.open(format);
                out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int numBytesRead;
                byte[] data = new byte[line.getBufferSize()/5];
                line.start();
                while (!isCancelled()) {
                    numBytesRead = line.read(data, 0, data.length);
                    out.write(data, 0, numBytesRead);
                    fos.write(data, 0, data.length);
                }
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception excp) {
                System.out.println("Error! Could not open Audio System line!");
                excp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: as you know loudness in English is equal to volume so this question has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618446/is-it-possible-to-change-the-volume-of-sound-by-manipulating-the-bytestream-that

Answer (score 1):

In the while loop, these steps:

1. convert the bytes to PCM values (depends on format, e.g., 16 bit is two bytes, 24 bit is three bytes, also pay attention whether it is big-endian or little-endian as this gives you the order of the bytes
2. multiply the PCM values by a volume factor (e.g., 1.1 to raise the volume a bit). You might want to also include a Math.min() to prevent the values from exceeding the range of the bits used to encode the values.
3. convert the PCM values back to bytes, according to your audio format specs

There may be a way to do this *instead* [via Controls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/controls.html). The plan I wrote about is basically how to do it manually, as written about in the linked tutorial in the last section "Manipulating the Audio Data Directly". Benefits: this is all within Java, instead of being dependent upon the given PC and OS (audio *Controls* are not guaranteed to exist). Also you have frame-level granularity. I think the *Controls* in the article tend to only enact changes at buffer boundaries.